# How to make individual columns for grouped excel columns using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel database which has columns grouped as shown below:
[image: Head of grouped data]
I have tried to create a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("filename.xls")
print(df[3])
```

which gives me the following output:

```
 0                1               2        3              4   ...      7       8               9          10                                        11
0    1   28AP2000000002  Andhra Pradesh  1999-00         Guntur  ...    0.00   50.00  Through NABARD  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE09350.00MT
1   13  28AP20010000013  Andhra Pradesh  2000-01      Anantapur  ...    0.00   32.00  Through NABARD  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE03200.00MT
2   14  28AP20010000228  Andhra Pradesh  2001-02   Vizianagaram  ...    0.00   23.65             NHB  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE02365.00MT
3   15  28AP20010000014  Andhra Pradesh  2001-02  East Godavari  ...    0.00   25.00  Through NABARD  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE02500.00MT
4   16  28AP20010000015  Andhra Pradesh  2001-02   Vizianagaram  ...    0.00   31.50  Through NABARD  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE03150.00MT
..  ..              ...             ...      ...            ...  ...     ...     ...             ...        ...                                       ...
80  92   28AAP0CS000036  Andhra Pradesh  2017-18         Guntur  ...  965.00  214.20             NHB  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE49760.00MT
81  93   28AAP0CS000029  Andhra Pradesh  2018-19         Guntur  ...   40.00   10.82             NHB  Completed     COLD / CA STORAGECA STORAGE23000.00MT
82  94   28AAP0CS000034  Andhra Pradesh  2018-19         Kadapa  ...  994.53  181.54             NHB  Completed  COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE414357.00MT
83  95   28AAP0CS000039  Andhra Pradesh  2019-20        Kurnool  ...  612.00  190.13             NHB  Completed   COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE49930.00MT
84  96   28AAP0CS000038  Andhra Pradesh  2019-20        Kurnool  ...  600.00  188.25             NHB  Completed  COLD / CA STORAGECOLD STORAGE410346.00MT
```

In the generated dataframe above, you can see that the last column is merged because of grouped tables in the excel file. Can anyone suggest a solution to separate it out based on the final column names?

Comment: Why are you using `read_html` on an Excel file? Is that a typo in your code?

Comment: I am using read_html because the file is generated using a website and if I use read_excel, it throws an error.
The error is: xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<div id='

Comment: I have made an edit to my comment above with the said error. Please check @BigBen

Comment: can you clarify the desired result (where exactly the last column should be split)? Or show the first few rows of the Excel file because with the current data, we don't know where is the limit between the 2 columns you are trying to split.

Comment: @Ssayan sure, I have updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to split the columns afterwards, I propose to get the proper columns from the reader. It works with `pd.read_excel()` and should also work with `pd.read_html()` according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). I can't test with `pd.read_html()` as I don't have a matching source.

The issue is that you are just passing the file and letting pandas decide how to read it. It is fine for a basic file where the first row is the column title and then the other ones the data. But when you have a different form as you have, you need to guide it.

Therefore, you can choose to skip the `n` first rows and let it know what the column names are. header is used to tell which row should be used for column names, since you don't have any row with all the titles, I chose to use `None` and manually add the column titles.

```py
# Use skiprows to indicate how many rows to ignore
df = pd.read_html("filename.xls", skiprows=12, header=None)
# Rename columns to match your file.
df.columns = ["SI. No", "Project Cc", "State", "Year of Sub", "District", "Name of E", "Project A", "Total Project"]
```